# Creating a directory in Samba share from OSX client always has ACL "mask:r-x"

Tags: osx, samba

I've had a few shares configured in **Samba 4.9.3** (Arch Linux), everything was fine. Access control was done via unix accounts and groups. Then I decided to change the running system.

I set up a Time Machine backup volume in Samba, introducing the `vfs_fruit` module. That part seems to have started the problems. Sources said that macOS can be picky and the module chain `catia fruit streams_xattr` needs to be enabled on *all* the shares, not just the Time Machine share. So I did that.

(The Time Machine backup went through with those settings. TBH I didn't try restoring yet and I'm a little scared of it.)

However, whenever I create a folder on a normal share (via Finder.app), it now gets unix permissions `drwxr-xr-x+` that differ from the `directory mask = 2770` that I configured for the share. Apart from that, it has these ACLs set:

```
> getfacl /mnt/dungeon/tmp/untitled\ folder
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/dungeon/tmp/untitled folder
# owner: nobody
# group: smb_tmp
user::rwx
user:nobody:rwx         #effective:r-x
group::rwx          #effective:r-x
group:smb_tmp:rwx       #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:nobody:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:smb_tmp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

The `mask::r-x` part seems to prevent my user (in group smb_tmp) from even renaming the "untitled folder" I created. If I set mask to `rwx` manually like this, the folder becomes editable:

```
sudo setfacl -m mask::rwx /mnt/dungeon/tmp/untitled\ folder
```

Changing the folder's permissions from Finder.app is not possible, it tells me I *don't have the necessary permission*.

If I create a folder in the same location from a Windows  8 client, it has the proper unix access rights and no ACLs set.

I also tried modifying my user's umask on the server, but changing that from the default `022` to `027` didn't change anything.

The other Samba options I tried are in the global section of [**my smb.conf**](https://gist.github.com/tanuva/3e0f37f6111b68e7010017e88294f0d7). None of them changed the ACLs of the folders I created.

**What do I need to do to have both Time Machine backup and group-owned shares work properly?**
I'm not particularly afraid of ACLs, but if I can get by without them that'd be just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the following global option:

```
fruit:nfs_aces = no
```

From the manpage of vfs_fruit:

> **fruit:nfs_aces = yes | no**
>
> A *global* option whether support for querying and modifying the UNIX mode of directory entries via NFS ACEs is enabled, default *yes*.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  Your answer would be more useful if it included a few details: What does this option do (a short extract from the documentation is enough)?  Is that setting all that's required to fix the OP's problem?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If only I had guessed that "NFS ACEs" could have something to do with ACL issues... :)

Comment: Depending on what you've been reading up on you might know or you might not.  ACE: **A**ccess **C**ontrol **E**ntry, which is part of an ACL: **A**ccess **C**ontrol **L**ist .  

For instance in the manpages of _nfs4_setfacl_ and _nfs4_getcfacl_ the acronym ACL is explained when it's mentioned the first time, but ACE isn't. In the manpage of _nfs4_acl_ both acronyms are explained.